# How to remove unselected items of dropdownlist in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for this question on internet since a while without success. 
I have a dropdownlist of some fruits. When an item is selected from the list, then the other items should be removed from the list. For example, if Apple is selected, then the other fruits should be removed and Apple only should stay in the list. => The function `removeUnselectedOptions()` does not perform consistently. here below the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Remove unselected items</title>
<script>
function removeUnselectedOptions() {
    var element = document.getElementById("fruitSelect");
    var length = element.length;
    var options = element.options;
    var selected = element.value;
    console.log(selected);
    console.log(length);
    var i = 0;
    do{
        console.log(i);
        console.log(options[i].value);
        console.log(selected);

        if(options[i].value != selected) {
            element.remove(i);
}
        i++;
   } while (i<length);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>

<br>
<select id="fruitSelect" size="5" onchange='removeUnselectedOptions();'>
    <option selected value="Select a fruit" >Select a fruit</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    </select>
    </form>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "*does not perform consistently*" mean, in context? What doesn't behave "*consistently*"? And, from a user-interface perspective, are you sure that removing unselected options is the best approach? What if the user wants to change their mind and choose another fruit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce your code to the following which gets the selected element's index, then loops backwards to remove it. Why backwards? Because if you loop forwards (like you'd normally do), the indexes change when you remove an element and it ends up leaving options as you probably noticed.

```js
function removeUnselectedOptions() {
    var element = document.getElementById("fruitSelect");
    var selected = element.selectedIndex;
    for (var i = element.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i != selected) element[i].remove()
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <br>
    <select id="fruitSelect" size="5" onchange='removeUnselectedOptions();'>
        <option selected value="Select a fruit">Select a fruit</option>
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Pear</option>
        <option>Banana</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

other ways is :

```
function removeUnselectedOptions(){
    var element = document.getElementById("fruitSelect");
    var options = element.options;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < element.length){
        if(options[i].selected) {
            element.innerHTML = '<option value="'+options[i].label+'">'+
                options[i].label+
                '</option>';
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/9xxrezpg/)